# Why would glShadeModel(GL_FLAT) not work?

Tags: opengl

To my understanding, `GL_FLAT` is supposed to make a face a single color. I can't get `GL_FLAT` to actually work though; it's as though my program is only using `GL_SMOOTH`. I'm using light sources, but both look the same.

[image]

The triangle should be just one color. Here's my scene rendering code. I no where mention `GL_SMOOTH`, and I've tried `GL_FLAT` everywhere (inits, main, before light/material definitions, before drawing, while drawing, after drawing, etc.)

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

//Light
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);

//Define Light source ...
//Define Material ...

//Draw Triangle
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);

glNormal3f(0,0,1);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glVertex3f( -.5, -.5, 0);
glVertex3f( 0, .5, 0);
glVertex3f( .5, -.5, 0);
glEnd();

glFlush();
```

That's it. Everything else in the program is the bare minimum it needs to run. Is `GL_FLAT` broken or something?

Comment: Have you tried adding a surface normal?

Comment: Yes, it's sticking out in the positive Z axis. I can see the triangle, but the shading isn't flat like I want, rather it looks smooth. The image linked between the two paragraphs shows my output for `GL_FLAT`

Comment: Do you have a different system you can test your code on? Based on what's shown here, I don't see a reason why you shouldn't get a flat shaded triangle.

Comment: Not at the moment, but I should probably start looking for another machine to test elsewhere.

Comment: This should work. What hw/driver? Be aware that you are hitting an ancient legacy code path in the driver. Especially by combining with GL_POLYGON. You should look into shaders and es2 like gl for the more stable path.

Comment: There are no shaders, just a light. It's in a Linux VM on a Windows machine (it may be the VM because my classmates can't get it to work either). I know this stuff is outdated haha, but it's what my professor wants to use, reasoning being that he can teach theory more easily with it. I'll look into what you guys suggested when I revisit openGL outside of the university. Thank you all for trying to help!

Comment: Disable light! Lighting follows another path.

Comment: @Luca: no it doesn't. The effect of `glShadeModel()` is well-specified, and combining it with lighting is not a problem at all. Judging from the code given so far, it should work. But I agree with @starmole in that this might easily expose some driver bugs.